# How to create an array from form fields separated for every fieldset

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I need an array from a HTML form fieldset.

I created a HTML form with some fields ...

```
    <input type='text' name='form[][1]' value='a'>
    <input type='text' name='form[][1]' value='b'>
    <input type='text' name='form[][1]' value='c'>

    <input type='text' name='form[][2]' value='a'>
    <input type='text' name='form[][2]' value='b'>
    <input type='text' name='form[][2]' value='c'>
... and so on ...
```

I need for every form-number

> form[][1]
>   form[][2]
>   form[][3]
>   ...

a separated array. The array have to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

)
```

But my array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => c
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => a
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => b
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => c
        )

)
```

Whats wrong with my form-fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your name structure like this,

```
form[1][]
```

To fetch and gather all the names and data in `form[1]` array and same for `form[2]`.

```
print_r($_POST['form']);
```

**Outputs to**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

)
```